# Example code for embedding SVG canvas in SWT project?

Tags: java, swt, svg

Is there a good example of how to include an SVG canvas into a Java SWT project (particularly [Holongate](http://www.holongate.org/contents.html), though I would be interested in any other options)? Additionally, I would need to support this SVG canvas on Mac OS X, Windows and Linux clients, in case an implementation relies on native libraries. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Use batik (http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/).
Render SVG into the image.
Display it in SWT container.
Portable.

Comment: I think Batik is Swing, not SWT.

Comment: "I think Batik is Swing"... No... Use batik to render JPEG (or whatever) and then display that in swt (or whatever)... the fun part is generating the region map to support interactivity.

Comment: This seems like a hack that doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: it is how it works, it is not a hack. 99% of batik is SVG rendering algorithm. How to embed it into particular framework - is technical details.

Comment: "With Batik, you can manipulate SVG documents anywhere Java is available. You can also use the various Batik modules to generate, manipulate and transcode SVG images in your applications or applets."  http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/

Answer (score 3):

We implemented this functionality by embedding a Batik Swing canvas into an SWT composite, see [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.ohf/plugins/org.eclipse.ohf.h3et.mif.ui/src/org/eclipse/ohf/h3et/mif/ui/viewers/MIFCanvas.java?revision=1.3&root=Technology_Project). It worked fine on Windows, but we couldn't scroll the canvas on Mac OS X.
However, the vast majority of our users were on Windows, so we didn't spend too much time trying to fix the Mac OS X bug.

Comment: The "here" link is broken.  Can you please provide an up-to-date link?

Answer (score 0):

Look at: [eclipse GMF](http://www.mail-archive.com/batik-users@xmlgraphics.apache.org/msg02782.html) they has written a class witch renders through 
org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt.internal.graphics.Graphics2DToGraphicsAdaptor
and Source code is in org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt.internal.svg.
SWTImageTranscoder.