# How use SVG as splash screen?

Tags: java, svg, eclipse-rcp

I use PDE and RCP. My tool has a splash image located in splash.bmp. In the build.properties I include the image into `bin.includes` (`bin.includes = splash.bmp`). In the a`pp.product` file I have the following code:

```
   <splash startupProgressRect="5,275,445,15" />
   <launcher name="app">
      <linux icon="/icons/running.xpm"/>
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>
```

I want to replace the `splash.bmp` with the `splash.svg`. I tried to replace `<bmp/>` with `<svg/>` but it did not work. Is it something that possible to do with Eclipse Photon?

**EDIT**: My custom splash handler:

```
public class MySplashHandler extends EclipseSplashHandler {
    private Image image;

    public ApplicationSplashHandler() {
        super();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void init(final Shell splash) {
        super.init(splash);
    }
}
```

How can I load the svg?

Comment: @greg-449 I added my custom eclipse handler. Is it possible to show to load the SVG?

Comment: `EclipseSplashHandler` is an internal class you should not be extending it. The official class is `BasicSplashHandler`. In either case you can put whaever you like in splash screen by overriding methods like `getContent`. For SVG you would have to use something like Batik - see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/804660/2670892)